# msAccess 2007 Passing form objects to a function

Tags: ms-access-2007

Since I am doing the same thing over and over, I would like to write a generic function that is passed the form that is calling the function, another form name that has a field with the value. A field on my form that is passing the value and a field off another form. I would think this should be easy.

for a simple example:

```
call setdefaultvalues(form1 as object, form2 as object, field1 as object, field2 as object)

function setdefaultvalues(form1 as ojbect, form2 as object, field1 as object, field2 as object)

If CurrentProject.AllForms(form1).IsLoaded Then
 form1.field1.defaultvalue = form2.field2
end if

end function
```

Can someone give me a hand with this.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to pass the names of objects & then reference...

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
    ' Pass the names of the objects.
    Call setdefaultvalues(Me.Name, Me.Name, "txtField1", "txtField2")
End Sub


Function setdefaultvalues(form1 As String, form2 As String, field1 As String, field2 As String)
    If CurrentProject.AllForms(form1).IsLoaded Then
        Forms(form1).Controls(field1).DefaultValue = Forms(form2).Controls(field2)
    End If
End Function
```